# Heroku No module named 'boto3'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, heroku

I am using flask. I am using AWS as authentication, when I installed boto3 it works good at my computer but when I tried to deploy my flask app into Heroku server it does not work and I got this error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'

this is my requirements.txt :

```
boto3==1.4.4
botocore==1.5.95
cffi==1.14.5
click==7.1.2
cryptography==3.4.7
docutils==0.17.1
ecdsa==0.14.1
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy-Session==1.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
gunicorn==20.1.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jmespath==0.10.0
jwt==1.2.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pyasn1==0.4.8
pycparser==2.20
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-jose==3.2.0
rsa==4.7.2
s3transfer==0.1.13
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.23
urllib3==1.26.4
Werkzeug==1.0.1
WTForms==2.3.3
```

Comment: (a) Are you entirely sure you've committed this file, and deployed the correct branch? (b) Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: (a) yes I'm sure (b) this is Pipfile  [[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
click = "==7.1.2"
flask = "==1.1.2"
flask-sqlalchemy = "==2.4.4"
flask-sqlalchemy-session = "==1.1"
gunicorn = "==20.0.4"
itsdangerous = "==1.1.0"
jinja2 = "==2.11.3"
markupsafe = "==1.1.1"
psycopg2 = "==2.8.6"
psycopg2-binary = "==2.8.6"
sqlalchemy = "==1.3.23"
Flask-WTF = "==0.14.3"
Werkzeug = "==1.0.1"
WTForms = "==2.3.3"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"

Comment: Please don't try to share code in comments. It's impossible to read. But that's your problem. See [gunicorn command not found, but it's in my requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60452279/354577), [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' in heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59116442/354577), [requirements.txt vs Pipfile in heroku flask webapp deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63252388/354577)